# Media Query Not Firing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

**The Goal**

The goal is to be make the grid system boxes amount per row change based on screen size. Here is an example

```
Screen Size   Boxes   Percent Width
1250px          3           33.3
750px           2           50
500px           1           100
```

**Current Progress**

I have created the grid system and the media queries

```
/* Max Width 1250px */
@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    .boxes {
        width: 33.3%;
    }
}

/* Max Width 750px */
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
    .boxes {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Max Width 500px */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
    .boxes {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

I current have the media queries that work at 750px and 500px however it skips the 1250px. Not sure what the difference between the 750px and the 1250px? Why it not working?

**JSFiddle -** https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lkm2f/1/

Comment: Your 750px and 1250px media queries have both 50% width.. so what you mean about "not working"? How they should work differently?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNWEPQ your queries work. Your css might be wrong though

Comment: @Hardy sorry i was copy and pasting the code to see if was spelling but still doesn't fire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar problem before.

You should use both `min-width` and `max-width` to set lower and upper bounds respectively.

Also your first two are redundant. Both give the `.boxes` class a width of 50%. It would be better to combine them into one, that serves both viewpoints

```
/* Max Width 1250px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1250px) {
    .boxes {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Max Width 500px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
    .boxes {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Using the above syntax is a great way to prevent confusion.

Edit: Media queries only work on ie9 and above. If you are using an older browser, the above will NOT work.

Second Edit: It looks like in media queries you need to add `only` before the type. For example

`@media only screen` instead of `@media screen`

Comment: Still not working as intended - https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lkm2f/2/ What if I add the .boxes width original css width-in a media query so like (min-width: 1251px) { .boxes { width:25%;}}?

Comment: That was a bad idea, completely messed XD

Comment: I'm on the latest safari and tested on chrome as well

Comment: Marking yours as answer as it will apply for people that have a similar problem with media queries, not the first time they have acted funny for me. Thank you!